# Experimental challenges of increasing the size of a Bose-Einstein condensate

Tags: experimental-physics, bose-einstein-condensate

My question is partially inspired by [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/148818/what-is-the-largest-number-of-bosons-placed-in-a-bec). I know that BECs have been created whose side lengths are on the order of microns, while others have managed to make a side length of approximately $1$ mm.

Let's say that I wanted to make a BEC with side lengths on the order of $1$ m. I recently found out that one problem that I would face is that the techniques of laser cooling and evaporative cooling aren't easily scalable, so they can't be used to create metre-long BECs. What sort of other experimental challenges would I face?

Comment: If we have a meter long BEC, then it would be jiggling the same as a single atom jiggles, except it’s one meter long, so then the jiggling of all that mass within the one meter long BEC can be transferED into electromechanical energy. Theoretically, the giant one meter long BEC mass could be used as free energy machine.